# Salesforce formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

may I know how to fulfil the requirement where if the material is not null, the user must insert size, flavour, and packing? When I run the below formula, it does not work like how it is supposed to do

```
IF(
not(ISBLANK(TEXT(Material__c))),
and(ISBLANK(TEXT(Size__c)), ISBLANK(TEXT(Flavour__c)), ISBLANK(TEXT(Packing__c))), 
and(not(ISBLANK(TEXT(Size__c))), not(ISBLANK(TEXT(Flavour__c))), not(ISBLANK(TEXT(Packing__c))))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the right way to do it. Remember if the condition is true then fire the error msg.

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Material__c))),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(TEXT(Size__c)),
        ISBLANK(TEXT(Flavour__c)),
        ISBLANK(TEXT(Packing__c))
    )
)
```